Why can't I define a key value in parent constructor if it's not in the child one
Why can't I put species in the constructor here but outside it is allowed? What can be done to fix this? For example,


class Humans {
  constructor(nameGiven) {
    this.nameGiven = nameGiven;
  }
  species = "Homo sapiens";
}

class Family extends Humans {
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log("We are a family")
  }
}

let Krishang = new Family("Krishang")



This code runs perfectly normal and I can understand that but...


class Humans {
  constructor(nameGiven) {
    this.nameGiven = nameGiven;
    species = "Homo sapiens";
  }
}

class Family extends Humans {
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log("We are a family")
  }
}

let Krishang = new Family("Krishang")



Throws me an error stating that species isn't  defined in Humans, Family and the object. Why so? I have already used the keyword extends. Please help

Also, I'm not a newbie but I haven't practiced since 4years so I am now asking very naive questions.

Use this.species = ... in the second example.

@RoryMcCrossan It doesn't work. Tried.

Works ok here: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/34dz9o7k/

Inside a method, you need to declare variables. Without a declaration, species would be a global variable, not an instance property, but ES6 doesn't allow creation of global variables in methods.

This is because you forgot to define this.species. Just species is never defined. Consider this:


    class Humans {
        constructor(nameGiven) {
            this.nameGiven = nameGiven;
            this.species = "Homo sapiens";
        }
    }

    class Family extends Humans {
        constructor(name, nameGiven) {
            super(nameGiven);
            this.familyName = name;
            console.log("We are a family")
        }
    }

    let Krishang = new Family("Krishang", "Rana");
    console.log(Krishang);



Note that I added the given name and the family name. Sorry if I did not understand your intent about names correctly, consider it just an example, not perfectly logical. I think you forgot to pass a parameter to the base class constructor from a derived constructor. Anyway, this change is off-topic, added just in case.
Note that you won't need this. in this.species if you use a different form of initialization, outside the constructor:
class Humans {
    constructor(nameGiven) {
        this.nameGiven = nameGiven;
    }
    // does not matter before or after constructor
    species = "Homo sapiens";
}

Maybe this form without .this confused you, but this is what it is. In case of species it looks more logical, because you don't modify this member so far. As soon as you want to modify it depending on constructor parameters, you can move it back to the constructor.
